# Truffle Pet Shop understanding App.js code

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at the following code ([link](https://github.com/joel-maws/truffle-pet-shop/blob/master/src/js/app.js)):

```
App = {

    web3Proverder: null,
    contracts: {},

    ...

    initContracts: function(){
        $.getJSON('Greeter.json', function(data) {
            var GreeterArtifact = data;
            App.contracts.Greeter = TruffleContract(GreeterArtifact)
            App.contracts.Greeter.setProvider(App.web3Provider)
        });
    },

    ...
}
```

It seems `contracts` starts as an empty object, and then `App.contracts.Greeter` is set equal to something. How is it that the `contracts` object has a `Greeter` attribute if `Greeter` is not defined anywhere in `app.js`.

Can somehow help explain this so I can better understand the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes can be dynamically added to objects in Javascript. So there is no need to define `Greeter` before setting it.